# Proper formatting of csv file in excel for analysis in r?

Tags: r, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I'm looking for help finding the correct way to format a csv file in excel to be imported in excel for data analysis.
All my data is numbers and it forms a table with 6 columns and 10 rows.
I want to be able to plot my data, run any kind of test (ANOVA, t - test, etc.), reformat by dropping columns or whatever else, do regressions, etc. I have worked with csv files in r in the past but I had trouble with certain functions not working properly (of the top of my head, tapply did not work for example).
Here's a simplified example of what it looks like.

| Nb in forest | nb in swamp | nb in urban |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 17 | 5 |
| 28 | 15 | 7 |
| 35 | 17 | 5 |
| 20 | 12 | 4 |
| 19 | 14 | 3 |
| 26 | 10 | 8 |

The way I format my csv files right now is that I put everything in a cell column. The terms at each row are separated by comma. The first row is used to for the name/category of each Help is very welcome, thank you!

[How I format csv files right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjcBy.png)

Comment: Just set the data on individual cells, forming a table. Excel has a `Save As` option to export as csv.  Or with R, you could use the openxlsx package to read Excel files with `read.xlsx`

Comment: I second on saving xlsx in Excel and importing that in R as one option to consider. Especially when those Excel csv exports are *only* used for feeding data into R, R code does not get considerably more complex when using xlsx for input, even when dealing with multiple sheets (if you choose to). Though having reproducible csv export from Excel can be bit tricky, leaves room for human error or at least requires you to handle it through macro.  There's also xlsx/xls parsing package included in Tidyverse, https://readxl.tidyverse.org/  .

Answer (score 0):

Each row should be a unique ID, like the point, or petri dish, or population where you collected the data. I would add a first column with a unique id for each sample. Then replace all of the spaces in the column names with an _ because R does not like spaces, it will automatically replace them with a . but that gets confusing later. Personally I would use nb_f, nb_s, nb_u. If the entire table is just nb data then just forest, swamp, urban. R is case sensitive so keep the capitalization consistent. Make sure there are no hidden spaces or tabs in the cells. Just do a find replace for each of these. Notepad ++ is a good text reader for cleaning hidden characters from datasets.